Requirement for a point to be in the interior of a triangle
In the geometry book by Moise and Downs, it is written that, 'A point lies in the interior of a triangle if it lies in the interior of each of the angles of the triangle,' and a subsequent question is asked if it's enough for the point to be in the interior of two of the angles of the triangle to guarantee that the point is inside of the triangle. I spent some time pondering and drawing figures and it seems to me that the answer to the question is 'yes.' Am I mistaken?

Hint: If a point $I$ lies in the interior of an angle $\angle ABC$, then $\angle ABI < \angle ABC$. Assume the point is in the interior of the triangle, and then show that (using a contradiction) that if $ \angle ABI < \angle ABC $ and $ \angle ACI < \angle ACB$, then $\angle BAI < \angle BAC$

You seem to have proved that if the point lies in the interior of the triangle and the interior of two of the angles, then it lies in the interior of the third angle whereas I am asking to prove or disprove that, 'If the point lies in interior of 2 of the angles, does it necessarily lie in the interior of the third angle'

That is what I am saying, it is true and it can proven using a contradiction. If you want to me to give you more details, I'll be a happy to post an answer

Yes, I will be grateful if you post an answer because it seems to me that you have assumed an extra assumption that the point lies inside the triangle.

I think I went with the wrong phrasing in my original comment, I will post an answer in a bit.

Yes since the other way is to relate to the sides line equations that takes advantage of the signs when inserted in the line equations. This is translated to your question as the sides are situated between the angle's lines - so on those side of the sides of the triangle.

Could you please write clearly. I didn't understand anything.

The points interior to $\angle ABC$ are exactly those that are on the same side of the line $\overline{AB}$ as $C$, and are on the same side of the line $\overline{BC}$ as $A$.
The points interior to $\angle BCA$ are exactly those that are on the same side of the line $\overline{BC}$ as $A$, and are on the same side of the line $\overline{AC}$ as $B$.
So points interior to both angles are on the same side of $\overline{AB}$ as $C$, and are on the same side of $\overline{AC}$ as $B$. Which is the condition needed for them to be interior to $\angle CAB$.
